# Get program title from process name in C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'd like to obtain the title of a program from the running processes name, using C#.

Example:

I know a program is called "msn.exe", and i want to obtain the title (name), "Windows Live Messenger" from the application. How would i go about doing that? Googling has left me at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) class might be helpful for you.

```
      var info = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv").FirstOrDefault();

        if (info != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName);
            Console.WriteLine(info.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription);
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for 64bit processes from a 32bit application. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the Description field of WMI's Win32_Process Class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394599%28VS.85%29.aspx

It looks scary and foreign but it shouldn't be much code, just a few lines, when you're done.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Look at `System.Diagnostics.Process.MainWindowTitle`.  It's not 100% consistent with the "Window Title" column in SysInternal's Process Explorer, but generally pulls the same thing.